TypeScript discriminated type on number property
I have a function that returns an object with an errno property. If errno is 0, then it has more properties:
type StatvfsInfo = {
    errno: 0;
    f_bsize: bigint;
    f_frsize: bigint;
    f_blocks: bigint;
    f_bfree: bigint;
    f_bavail: bigint;
    f_files: bigint;
    f_ffree: bigint;
    f_favail: bigint;
    f_fsid: bigint; 
    f_flag: bigint;
    f_namemax: bigint;
}

type StatvfsError = {
    errno: number;
}

export function statvfs(path: string): StatvfsInfo | StatvfsError;

I'm trying to call it like this:
const result = statvfs("/path");
if (!result.errno) {
    // If `errno` is 0, these properties are set
    const total = result.f_blocks * result.f_frsize;
    const free = result.f_bavail * result.f_frsize;
    console.log({total, free}); 
}
else {
    // If `errno` is set, no other properties
    console.log({error: result.errno}); 
}

But the !result.errno (as well as result.errno === 0) condition is not enough to infer the type, so accessing the properties results in an error:
Property 'f_blocks' does not exist on type 'StatvfsInfo | StatvfsError'.
  Property 'f_blocks' does not exist on type 'StatvfsError'

What is the correct way to define the type to do it?

0 is a number so those don't discriminate. Is there some finite list of possible nonzero errno values? Or is it completely unknown? Assuming it's unknown, you'd need to write a custom type guard function to discriminate that data structure without changing it, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz It is the errno value from Linux. It's only defined to be 0 on success, and non-zero on error. (There are possible values but the implementation is free to return any non-zero value on error)

use result.errno !== 0 to narrow it

@DanielA.White you should test that; it doesn't work. Or rather, it only works to narrow to the thing OP doesn't care about, not to the code that looks for f_blocks, etc

user7401478, so then does this approach work for you? Is it important for you to check errno to do the distinguishing? Or does just checking for one of the f_* props, as described in the answer below suffice?

@jcalz Ideally I'd want to preserve the Linux errno semantics (if 0 aka no error, then fields available, else no fields as error occurred)

So I'll ask again: does this approach work for you? If so I'll write an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?
